# Dynamic Vue Router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am researching whether a vue router is the best approach for the following scenario:

I have a page containing 'n' number of divs. Each of the divs have different content inside them. When a user clicks on a button in the div, I would like the div to open in a separate browser window (including its contents).

- Can a route name/component be created on the fly to route to? Since I have 'n' number of divs, that are created dynamically, I cannot hard-code name/components for each one

  <router-link :to="{ name: 'fooRoute'}" target="_blank">
     Link Text
   </router-link>
- I want to avoid the same component instance being used (via route with params) since I may want multiple divs to be open at the same time (each one in their own browser window)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the link is opening in a separate window, it makes no sense to use a `<router-link>` component as the application will load from scratch in any case. You can use an anchor element instead and generate the `href` property dynamically for each div.

To answer your questions:

1. A route name cannot be created dynamically since all routes must be defined at the beginning, when the app (along with router) is being initialized. That said, you can have a [dynamic route](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html) and then dynamically generate different paths that will be matched by that route.
2. There is no way for the same component instance to be reused if it's running in a separate browser window/tab.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I'm not sure I understand the first part. The router-link comes with a target=_blank attribute. I'm not sure how that differs from If I use an a/href

Comment: The entire point of using `<router-link>` instead of `<a>` is for your app to detect the route change and "hijack" it. Instead of making a new request to the server, your app internally updates its state, navigates to the correct component and manually changes the browser URL using `history.pushState`. But this is only possible in the same window - by forcing the browser to open a new window, there is no way for the current app instance to be preserved, a fresh page load will inevitably happen.

Comment: @mzgajner Maybe you can hep me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57836601/how-can-make-dynamyc-routes-on-the-vue-router

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create dynamic router name.

`profileList.vue`

```
<template>
  <main>
    <b-container>
      <b-card
        v-for="username in ['a', 'b']"
        :key="username"
      >
        <b-link :to="{ name: profileType + 'Profile', params: { [profileType + 'name']: username }}">Details</b-link>
    </b-container>
  </main>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'profileList',

  data () {
    return {
      profileType: ''
    }
  },

  watch: {
    // Call again the method if the route changes.
    '$route': function () {
      this.whatPageLoaded()
    }
  },

  created () {
    this.whatPageLoaded()
  },

  methods: {
    whatPageLoaded () {
      this.profileType = this.$route.path // /user or /place
    }
  }
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style>
</style>
```

`b-container`, `b-card`, `b-link` are taken from bootstrap-vue, so you can freely change it.

`router.js`

```
const router = new Router({
  mode: 'hash',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  linkExactActiveClass: 'active',
  routes: [
    // USERS
    {
      path: '/user/:username',
      name: userProfile,
      component: userProfile
    },
    {
      path: '/user',
      name: 'userList',
      component: profileList
    },

    // PLACES
    {
      path: '/place/:placename',
      name: placeProfile,
      component: placeProfile
    },
    {
      path: '/place',
      name: 'placeList',
      component: ProfileList
    }
  ]
})
```